# AMPScript Get Xml and Rowset

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I'm trying to get a XML through HTTPGet by getting one element of that DOM, but my code doesn't work

```
%%[ 
   SET @xml = HTTPGet("http://ovc.catastro.meh.es/ovcservweb/OVCSWLocalizacionRC/OVCCallejero.asmx/ConsultaProvincia")
   SET @res = BuildRowsetFromXml(@xml, "/consulta_provinciero/provinciero/prov", 1)
   SET @rc =  RowCount(@res)
   outputLine (v(@rc));
]%%
```

What am I doing wrong?

This is so simple, I've read all documentation about this...

Any help?

Comment: What's not working?

Comment: @rc = 0, but in the xml are a lot elevents

Comment: I'd suggest taking a look at how to reference nodes via XPATH.  If you have multiple matches, then you'll need to iterate through them: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bmarketing-cloud%5D+xpath+is%3Aanswer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the namespace that's causing trouble with your XPATH query...

```
SET @xml = HTTPGet("http://ovc.catastro.meh.es/ovcservweb/OVCSWLocalizacionRC/OVCCallejero.asmx/ConsultaProvincia")
SET @xml = REPLACE(@xml, ' xmlns="http://www.catastro.meh.es/"',"")
```

There are handy tools online and developer tools to test your XPATH queries. I used [this one](http://codebeautify.org/Xpath-Tester) to debug your expression.

For what I think you're trying to do, you'll likely need build two rowsets made up of "//np" and "//cpine" or do an inner loop with a further XPATH query to pull out the child elements.

Comment: It works! 

Thank you

Comment: Why can not I see that namespace when I print @xml value before REPLACE function ?

Comment: If you're doing send preview of the HTML, the content type of the page is text/HTML and your browser interprets the XML in the page as HTML and just shows you the element values and not attribute values. Think of an anchor tag.... you browser displays the "Click Here" element's value and not the value of the href attribute - "http://www.mysite.com". If you switch the the text version of the email, you'll see a fairly ugly representation of the XML in all it's glory.

Answer (score 0):

Could be the `outputline()` function.  You don't need to use the `v()` function to reference an AMPScript variable inside of an AMPScript block:

```
%%[ 
   var @xml, @rc 
   SET @xml = HTTPGet("http://ovc.catastro.meh.es/ovcservweb/OVCSWLocalizacionRC/OVCCallejero.asmx/ConsultaProvincia")
   SET @res = BuildRowsetFromXml(@xml, "/consulta_provinciero/provinciero/prov", 1)
   SET @rc =  RowCount(@res)
   outputLine (concat("rc: ",@rc));
]%%
```